# How to enumerate all floating point values in between min and max

Tags: c++, floating-point

for an efficient random number generator for unique floating point values I'd like to know more about floating point values. I'm going to split my question in two parts.

1. How do I find out how many floats lie in between min and max (including both)?

I'm looking for a implementation of the method:

```
size_t numOfFloats(const float min, const float max);
```

Which considers all possible float values given the maximum precision of the data type.

2. How do I enumerate all possible float values in between min and max (including both)?

I'm looking for a implementation of the method:

```
vector<float> enumAllFloats(const float min, const float max);
```

The size of the vector returned shall always be equal to the return value of the method my first question.

C++11 is allowed if required.

Comment: You mean values that can be stored in a float variable?

Comment: Look into the details of the IEEE754 float formats and do some bit manipulating.

Comment: And you obviously mean the IEEE 754 standard for storing floats?

Comment: Yes, I mean that, like I wrote. [While not guarenteed, I´m pretty sure his device uses this format too, and if necessary it can be checked in C++11].

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Be careful using this. Floats are not uniformly distributed over the real line. For example, about half the floats in [1.5, 3] are in [1.5, 2].

Comment: This just seems like a bad idea

Comment: @deviantfan I guess Petr talks to rava in his second comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ieee754 representation of floats to map them to int. Then, do the maths with ints.

**Note** that the following code is not adapted to negative numbers, and do not take into account special floats values (NaN, infinities...)

```
size_t numOfFloats(const float min, const float max){
    // assert 0 <= min <= max
    // assert sizeof(float) == sizeof(int32_t)
    const int32_t min_i = *reinterpret_cast<const int32_t*>(&min);
    const int32_t max_i = *reinterpret_cast<const int32_t*>(&max);
    return max_i-min_i+1;
}
```

Also, you can easily list them when you know the mapping with ints:

```
void print_successive_floats(const float min, const float max){
    const int32_t min_i = *reinterpret_cast<const int32_t*>(&min);
    const int32_t max_i = *reinterpret_cast<const int32_t*>(&max);
    for(int32_t i = min_i; i<=max_i; ++i){
        float f = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&i);
        std::cout << f << std::endl;
    }
}
```

For completeness, in order to match your API:

```
vector<float> enumAllFloats(const float min, const float max){
    vector<float> out;
    out.reserve(numOfFloats(min, max));
    const int32_t min_i = *reinterpret_cast<const int32_t*>(&min);
    const int32_t max_i = *reinterpret_cast<const int32_t*>(&max);
    for(int32_t i = min_i; i<=max_i; ++i){
        float f = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&i);
        out.push_back(f);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Beware of huge vectors =)

Comment: This is so damn elegant. :)

Comment: As long as you don't pass negative infinity as a minimum. That's a legal IEEE754 value, but viewed as an integer it's smaller than -NaN.

Comment: @MSalters the code above needs some care with negative values. And doesn't take care of float special value as you noticed. Answer edited for that matter, thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [nextafterf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nextafter) to enumerate all representable floats:

```
vector<float> enumAllFloats(const float tmin, const float tmax) {
  vector<float> res;
  for (float x = tmin; x < tmax; x = nextafterf(x, tmax))
    res.push_back(x);
  res.push_back(tmax);
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume your target architecture uses the standard IEEE representation for floats (IEEE754, if I am not mistaken).

One of properties of this representations is that adjacent floats of the same sign have adjacent representations, that is if you treat the (32-bit) binary representation of some `float` as a (32-bit) `int`, that adjacent floats of the same sign will have the corresponding `int`s differ by exactly one.

So if both your `min` and `max` are of the same sign, then you can convert them to `int`s and then do a simple loop.

Something like (code adapted from [here](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/stupid-float-tricks-2/), which I also suggest as a source for more information):

```
/* See
https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/tricks-with-the-floating-point-format/
for the potential portability problems with the union and bit-fields below.
*/
union Float_t
{
    int32_t i;
    float f;
};

vector<float> enumAllFloats(const float min, const float max) {
    std::vector<float> result;
    Float_t fl;
    fl.f = min;
    result.push_back(fl.f);
    for (; fl.f <= max; fl.i++)
        result.push_back(fl.f);
    return result;
}
```

If `min` and `max` can have different signs, you will have to loop separately over positive and negative parts of the range. Also, maybe you will have to swap `min` and `max` for the code above if both are negative.

---

However, if you indeed want to use it for RNG, be careful, because those floats will not be distributed evenly in the `[min, max]` range.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Interesting property of floats, I didn't know that.